# PDO read SQLite file always overriding existing file

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm creating dynamicaly a SQLite file. The file well created, the table and all data are inserted to.

But when I try to access the file, the file is always overrided with an empty one. I've tried to use several parameters as filepath in order to make sure the file exists, and it does, but yet, it's always overrided.

Take a look at my function :

```
    $filename = (new \Package\Utils\Database())::FILE_NAME;
    $path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "Package/Utils/" ;
    $filepath = $path . $filename;

    if(file_exists(DBFILE)) {
        $db = new PDO('sqlite:'.DBFILE); //current file overrided here
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM category"); //so here, $stmt is false cause category doesn't exist
        $data['categories'] = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $tables = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
  WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' ORDER BY 1")->fetchAll(); //always empty cause the file is overrided

    } else die('error');
```

Comment: I notice that you carefully prepare a `$filepath` but then never use it, instead you're using `DBFILE`. Perhaps you're confused?

Comment: Nop,  both of those variables are equals (it was just for tests)